# Is the word "bestellt" needed in this sentence?

Tags: participle

> Um die Wirtschaft ist es noch schlechter bestellt als zu Mugabes Zeiten.

My translation for this sentence is this:

> The economy is worse than Mugabe’s time

I don’t understand the meaning of *bestellt* here. I think it is not the predicate of the sentence, which is *ist* if I am right - and what meaning does it have in this sentence?

Comment: What would be your alternative back translation? As constructed the verb _bestellt_ is needed, yes.

Comment: Shouldn't something be added to the english phrase to make it correct? "... is worse than **during** M's time" compares the economy in two times, while the original phrase compares economy and time. (Please correct me if **during** is not the right word, I'm not sure right now...)

Answer (score 7):

> Es ist um "etwas" schlecht bestellt

is an idiom that means that this "etwas" is in a poor shape/condition.
You can't leave out the *bestellt*.